# Python3 newbie needing advice

Tags: python

Hey everyone I am brand new to coding and back end computing in general. I have been at it about 3 weeks and thought I would take a crack at writing my first app. Most of my app is working just fine but I cannot figure out how to get the system to accept the new input and apply it to my functions after loop() runs. help please!

```
from os import sys

def say_bye():
    print("GoodBye!")
    sys.exit()

def loop():
    print()
    print("Would you like to enter another value?")
    choice2 = input('y/n: ')
    if choice2 == 'y':
        print()
        amount = float(input("enter another price: "))
        rate = float(input("tax rate: "))
        print()
        return in_page(), tot_with_tax_exit(), print(tot_with_tax()), loop()
    else:
        return say_bye()

def tot_with_tax():
    tax = (amount * rate)
    total = ("Your total after tax is", tax + amount)
    return total

def tot_with_tax_exit():
    if amount == int(0):
        print('would you like to exit')
        choice = input('y/n?: ')
        if choice == 'y':
            print()
            return say_bye()
        else:
            return tot_with_tax()

def in_page():
    print()
    print("Welcome to the tax tool!")
    print()
    print("Please enter your total price, and tax rate.")

in_page()
amount = float(input("enter price: "))
tot_with_tax_exit()
rate = float(input("tax rate: "))
print(tot_with_tax())
loop()
```

Comment: I don't see what exactly is the problem. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: your code has lot of unnecessary function calls can you explain what exactly your code is doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your problem was that after the initial `tot_with_tax()` gets calculated, it would continue to return the same value regardless of new inputs. At least that is what I noticed when I ran your code. Check out where I commented "HERE". I just modified `tot_with_tax()` to take two variables `tot_with_tax(amount, rate)`. Now you're passing in the new amount and rate to the function each time you want a new calculation.

```
from os import sys

def say_bye():
    print("GoodBye!")
    sys.exit()

def loop():
    print()
    print("Would you like to enter another value?")
    choice2 = input('y/n: ')
    if choice2 == 'y':
        print()
        amount = float(input("enter another price: "))
        rate = float(input("tax rate: "))
        print()
        return in_page(), tot_with_tax_exit(), print(tot_with_tax(amount, rate)), loop() # <--- HERE
    else:
        return say_bye()

def tot_with_tax(amount, rate): # <---- HERE
    tax = (amount * rate)
    total = ("Your total after tax is", tax + amount)
    return total

def tot_with_tax_exit():
    if amount == int(0):
        print('would you like to exit')
        choice = input('y/n?: ')
        if choice == 'y':
            print()
            return say_bye()
        else:
            return tot_with_tax()

def in_page():
    print()
    print("Welcome to the tax tool!")
    print()
    print("Please enter your total price, and tax rate.")

in_page()
amount = float(input("enter price: "))
tot_with_tax_exit()
rate = float(input("tax rate: "))
print(tot_with_tax(amount, rate)) # <--- HERE
loop()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed and it was right in front of my face for the last several hours of building complex solutions i couldnt get to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the values to the function to_with_tax()  here is the code with the changes that make it work.

```
from os import sys

def say_bye():
    print("GoodBye!")
    sys.exit()

def loop():
    print()
    print("Would you like to enter another value?")
    choice2 = input('y/n: ')
    if choice2 == 'y':
        print()
        amount = float(input("enter another price: "))
        rate = float(input("tax rate: "))
        print()
        return in_page(), tot_with_tax_exit(), print(tot_with_tax(amount, rate)), loop()
    else:
        return say_bye()

def tot_with_tax(amount, rate):
    tax = (amount * rate)
    total = ("Your total after tax is", tax + amount)
    return total

def tot_with_tax_exit():
    if amount == int(0):
        print('would you like to exit')
        choice = input('y/n?: ')
        if choice == 'y':
            print()
            return say_bye()
        else:
            return tot_with_tax()

def in_page():
    print()
    print("Welcome to the tax tool!")
    print()
    print("Please enter your total price, and tax rate.")

in_page()
amount = float(input("enter price: "))
tot_with_tax_exit()
rate = float(input("tax rate: "))
print(tot_with_tax(amount, rate))
loop()
```

Comment: I really appreciate this man you have no idea i was trying to write a whole separate function to change inputs it was a mess still learning over here.

Answer (score 0):

To validate user inputs, use a while True loop.

```py
while True:
    name = input("What's your name?: ")
    if name != "": # If the user entered a name
        break # Exit the loop
    # Else the program will keep asking
    # Until the user enters name.
```

Here's a simplified version of your code with that implemented:

```py
from os import sys


print("Welcome to the tax tool!")
print()
print("Please enter your total price, and tax rate.")

def taxed(amount, rate):
    tax = amount * rate
    total = "Your total after tax is $" + str(tax + amount)
    return total

while True:
    amount = float(input("Enter price: "))
    rate = float(input("Tax Rate: "))

    if amount >= 0 and rate >= 0:
        print (taxed(amount, rate))

        while True:
            again = input("Would you like to enter another value? (y/n): ")
            if again == "n":
                print("GoodBye!")
                sys.exit()
            if again == "y":
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to fill in the quantities amount and rate in your function tot_with_tax(). In that case you might want to pass in the arguments into the function.

Thus the function handle would be:

```
def tot_with_tax(amount, rate):
```

And you would call it by saying:

```
return in_page(), tot_with_tax_exit(amount, rate), print(tot_with_tax(amount, rate)), loop()
```

When calling tot_with_tax(), you don't need to name the arguments amount and rate if you don't want to, for example, if you had two states i.e CA and FL, you could pass in:

```
return tot_with_tax(amount_CA, rate_CA)

or

return tot_with_tax(amount_FL, rate_FL)
```

And either would get translated into an amount and rate inside the function.

Also one quick tip, you don't want to put in arbitrary parenthesis in python, since that signifies a type of variable called a tuple.

So instead of doing this:

```
tax = (amount * rate)
```

Do this:

```
tax = amount * rate
```